# Will multiple while loops with the same condition initiate sequentially or simultaneously?

Tags: python, while-loop

Suppose I have multiple while loops based on the same variable, say

```
#loop 1
count = 0
while count < len(list): #where list is non-empty
    do stuff
    count = count + 1
delete some things from list
count = 0

#loop 2
while count < len(list): #where list is still non-empty but shorter than before
    do other stuff
    count = count + 1
delete more things from list
count = 0

#loop 3
while 0 < len(list): #where list is less than before but still nonempty
    while count < len(list): #nested within above while loop
        do even more stuff
        count = count + 1
    delete more items of the list
    count = 0
#list is now empty
```

Will these 3 while loops all trigger at the same time? Or will it initiate one at a time?

Comment: Put in some prints and find out.

Comment: Everything in basic python happens sequentially from the top down. You can always test it yourself

Comment: Spoiler: without threading or multiprocess, it's sequential.

Comment: Also `while list:` is the same as `while 0 < len(list):` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A program is a list of instructions.

They are executed from the top to the bottom.

Therefore the answer is **no**, they will not trigger at the same time.

---

E.g. What happens here?

```
import time
print('one')
time.sleep(1)
print('two')
time.sleep(1)
print('three')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a line-by-line execution from top to bottom of your program since you aren't multi-threading/processing. Hence, it will run sequentially and not parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test case:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

count = 0
while items:
    print(items.pop(0))
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        break

print("new while")
while items:
    print(items.pop(0))
    count += 1
    if count == 6:
        break

print("last while")
while items:
    print(items.pop(0))
    count += 1
```

Due to Python's GIL, many items like lists can be operated on concurrently as well, without dividing them up:

```
import threading, time
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def stuff(x, count_limit):
    t = threading.current_thread()
    count = 0
    while items:
        print(t.name + ": " + str(items.pop(0)) + " count: " + str(count) + "\n", end = "")
        count += 1
        if count_limit:
            if count == count_limit:
                break

threads = []

counts = [3,6,False]
for x, count in enumerate(counts):
    t = threading.Thread(target = stuff, args = (items, count,))
    t.name = "Thread " + str(x)
    threads.append(t)
```

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()